# Django Login/Signup With own users Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using phpMyAdmin for the database.
I am creating own user table and store user information in it without extending the Django User Model. Now, I have a problem in the login part. I can't get data from users table with objects and authenticate function is also not working. 
Here is my code:

#### View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .form import SignUp,UserLogin
from .models import users
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,get_user_model,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def Userlogin(request):
   form=UserLogin()
   if request.method == 'POST':
      user_login = UserLogin(request.POST or None)
    if user_login.is_valid():
        username = request.POST.get('email', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        getInfo=users.objects.get(email='example@mail.com')
        user=authenticate(email=username,password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
           login(request,user)
           return redirect('/')
args={'form':form}
return render(request,'html/login.html',args)
```

#### form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import users
class UserLogin(forms.Form):
     email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs=
                {   'value':'', 
                    'class':'form-control'}))
     password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                {   'type': '', 
                    'value':"mukul", 
                    'class':'form-control'}))
```

#### model.py

```
from django.db import models
class users(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

What I need:-

1. Run `authenticate()`. its not working, I don't know want is wrong. Should, i want to create new `authenticate()` in forms.py.
2. if I call `users.objects.get(email='example@mail.com')`, it's also not working in view.py but if run in python shell it works very well.

   ```
   getInfo = users.objects.get(email='example@mail.com')
   ```

show error:

> class users do not have objects member

#### I have Some Question

**if I create own users model**

1. Do I want to create own authenticate function for login?
2. Do I want to create `objects.get()`, `objects.all()`,
   `objects.create_user()` etc?

Help me, I am working on a project and I am stuck on this errors.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your Questions First:
if I create own users model:
Do I want to create own authenticate function for login? Yes
Do I want to create objects.get(), objects.all(), objects.create_user() etc? Nope

You Need to Fix Errors:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import SignUp,UserLogin #Wrong Import
from .models import users
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,get_user_model,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def Userlogin(request):
   form=UserLogin()
   if request.method == 'POST':
    user_login = UserLogin(request.POST or None)   #Indentation
    if user_login.is_valid():
        username = request.POST.get('email', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        getInfo=users.objects.get(email='example@mail.com')
        user=authenticate(email=username,password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
           login(request,user)
           return redirect('/')
   args={'form':form} #Fix Indentation
   return render(request,'html/login.html',args) #Fix Indentation
```

Models.py

```
class users(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Also What you need to do is Run Migrations.
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate

This would Create the Model in the Database Automatically and thus ORM of Django would work for .objects.get

## =========== Update =========

Change Models.py (Extend the Default Users as It already Contains Email and Password Fields)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as AuthUser, UserManager

# Extend the base User model
class User(AuthUser):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    active = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField("last modified")

    objects = UserManager()
```

Override the Django Model Backend for User

```
class CustomAuth(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(**credentials):
        return super(CustomAuth, self).authenticate(**credentials)

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):    
        # Check the username/password and return a User.
        if username != None and password != None:
            # Get the user
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=username)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    logger.info('User is authenticated, logging user in')
                    return user
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
           return None
```

now you can use it as:

```
user = authenticate(username='test@gmail.com', password='testUser')
```

for Further Reference: https://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html

Comment: I have a table in the database with migration and I complete my signUp step but I have no idea how to create authenticate() for login and can you tell me how to create it as well as why I get an error in users.objects.get(email='') in Web, but its work in shell.

Comment: from .models import users 
Did you Tried from models import users. The Users Side is due to Import Issue!

Comment: For Authenticate, You can generate a JWT Token and Check it in Cookie Accordingly!

Comment: Thanks Alot, Your Code and the Reference Worked Out Great for me!